# Angular 2 - Forms showing ngvalid while inputs are having nginvalid

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, validation

the forms shows ngvalid as i have give the code like this

```
 <form novalidate class="pop-form" (submit)="signUp()" #regForm="ngForm"> 
    <div class="group">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="signUpData.name"
           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
           placeholder="&nbsp;"  required=""
           id="upName" name="upName" #upName="ngModel">
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>{{'Name' | translate}}</label>

    <div *ngIf="upName.errors && (upName.dirty || upName.touched)"
         class="alert alert-danger alert-new">
      <div [hidden]="!upName.errors.required">
        {{'Enter username and password' | translate}}
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
......................
...................
</form>
```

the console below shows [image]

that there are invalid elements in form but it shows valid.
how it can be solved, the issue effects when disabling button when form is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curious why you are using 'ngModelOptions' here.

This is from the docs:

> standalone: Defaults to false. If this is set to true, the ngModel
>   will not register itself with its parent form, and will act as if it's
>   not in the form. This can be handy if you have form meta-controls,
>   a.k.a. form elements nested in the  tag that control the display
>   of the form, but don't contain form data.

This seems to be the opposite of what you want?

Comment: oh! My mistake, forgot about that